# How to send image from App Inventor to a java web service that uses FormDataParam

Tags: java, web-services, app-inventor, form-parameter, postfile

I've created a java web service that uploads an image to a folder. It works fine from a html form, [but when i tried to send the image from app inventor using PostFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlL6d.jpg)
[image]

I get error 1104, which as I read means that either there's a problem with the url or with the internet connection. I know it's not my internet connection, so it has to be the url. I also noticed that in the web service [the upload function requires a specific parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E51U.jpg)
[image]

that contains the image, I don't know if that's what's causing the problem or how to specify in App Inventor that the image belongs to that parameter like on a [html form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXhu1.jpg).
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Taifun, here's my solution. I simply send my image from App Inventor to a php file that i have running on a http server and from that php i send the image to the java web service using **curl**, specifying the name of the parameter and using the **file_get_contents('php://input')** function to obtain the image received from App Inventor.

```
$upload_url = 'http://192.168.1.77:8081/ImageProcessing/api/file/upload';
$params = array(
 'photo'=>file_get_contents('php://input')
);  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $upload_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the web component of App Inventor is not able to understand `multipart/formdata`.

You can upload a file to your web server using the PostFile method [see this example](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php), alternatively use the [ftp extension](https://puravidaapps.com/ftp.php).

Comment: thanks for letting me know App Inventor does't work with that, I actually managed to make it work by using a php as a "bridge" between App Inventor and my web service and works fine.

Comment: you might want to add your solution as answer including your "bridge" php script ... this might help others with a similar question in future... thank you.